# Description from Graph api

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

Hi i want to extract the informations of an event from graph api.
I'm using this code:

$link is the url of the event

```
$position=strpos($link,'eid=')+4;
$ID=substr($link, $position);
$url="http://graph.facebook.com/$ID";
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
$obj=json_decode($homepage,true);

$location=$obj["location"];

$de=$obj["description"];
```

With this code i get all the information but not the description.
my page catch the description only when the description of the event is very short (1 line of text)

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works even with long one. Example here:

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c3e45/2

Comment: if i visualize it in a page it goes.the problem is when i put it in the action page to save it in my DB –

Comment: @MicheleBraglia: so problem is in another snippet

Comment: After the definition of all the variable i just make a query and i don't modify the description

$query_sql="INSERT INTO EVENTI VALUES('$conta','$id','$titolo','$band','$loc','$v alore','$de','$google ','$face','$logo',1)";
$result=mysql_query($query_sql,$myconn);